# C++ virtual function: Base class function is called instead of derived

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual-functions, overload-resolution

I have following code snippet:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void print(char a){ std::cout << " Base\n"; }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void print(float a)  { std::cout << " Derived\n"; }
};

int main() {
    base* d = new derived;
    d->print(1.5);
}
```

Output is `Base`.

Why is the output coming from the base function and not from the derived one?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `Base* d = new Derived;`, the type of the class is Base, as printed by `typeid(d).name()`, so this instance doesn't have access to child class methods. If you change the type to Derived, you'll call the child method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void print(char a) {
        std::cout << " Base " << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void print(float a) {
        std::cout << " Derived " << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived* d = new Derived;
    std::cout << "class type is: " << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
    d->print(1.5);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
class type is: P7Derived
 Derived
```

Furthermore, declaring the parent class `print` method `virtual` doesn't allow an instance of Base to call the child version of `print` because the child hasn't overridden it (different headers). Creating an instance of Base with `Base *d = new Derived;` and changing the Derived `print` method header to `void print(char a)` in the Derived class would allow you to call the child `print` method and output `Derived`, even from an instance of Base, using the `virtual` keyword.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void print(char a) {
        std::cout << " Base " << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void print(char a) {
        std::cout << " Derived " << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* d = new Derived;
    std::cout << "class type is: " << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
        d->print(1.5);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
class type is: P4Base
 Derived
```

Comment: I think there is not any condition that name should start from capital letter.
Secondly, in derived class both of the versions should be there, and then float is better match than char.

Comment: Not from a compiler perspective (you could name everything random-cased gibberish and it'd be 100% happy), but from a human perspective it's the standard convention (open any C++ book or look at any C++ code on Github or Stack Overflow and see). On your second point: what is your question and expected output, then? It seems to me you were expecting to see "derived" but if that's not the case, what are you asking about?

Comment: I agree with you, as best coding practices goes .
My Question is why the output in this case is "base", why not "derived"?

Comment: Ah, I see a little more clearly what's going on. I'll try to edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have not **overridden** the function in the base class, you have **overloaded** it: The version in the derived class takes a `float` as an argument, and is quite a different beast from the base class method which takes a `char`. Moreover, the `float` version in the derived class **shadows** the base class version: The base class version becomes inaccessible for calls on the derived type.

As such, the following code

```
Derived d;
d.print('a');
d.print(1.5);
```

will print

```
Derived
Derived
```

because the call is resolved by the compiler to the only version of `print()` that's available in `Derived`.

Likewise, when you call `d->print(1.5)` through a pointer to `Base`, the derived class' version is inaccessible to the call: The compiler looks at the base class, sees that there is no `print()` method defined with a `float` argument, and converts the argument to `char` instead. It then calls the only implementation of `print(char)`, which happens to be supplied by the base class.

---

If you simply change the signature of the `print()` method in the derived class to match that of the base class, the odd behavior will go away.

Comment: "will print". Not really. Try it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Ah, good catch :-) Completely forgot about shadowing. Will update my answer to take care of this. Thanks.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Done.